# Splash screen appearing when navigating between views react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing a react native app that was ejected from expo.

The splash screen worded fine at the beginning but I changed it in between and the splash screen now appears when navigating between views.

[image]

The splash screen appears behind every navigation and this is creating a major problem when navigating in the dark mode because the splash screen is white and it is jarring.

**This only happens on Android.**

Please suggest what can be done to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue(seeing blurred vision of previous screen when navigating) but not with splash screens. I fixed it by making animationEnabled as false in navigationOptions like below

```
ScreenName:{
  title: "ScreenName",
  screen: ScreenName,
  navigationOptions: {
    headerShown: false,
    animationEnabled: false
  }
}
```

I don't know if it will work or not for your case. just sharing.

Comment: Hey Thanhal, thanks for the answer. Disabling the animation does not remove the issue. It seems to be more of a flicker of splash screen flashing between changing views.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem